# Required solution for all Textbox on value change event - generic way

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt2

In my application we are using 
   1. Screen are designed using UIBinder with a view class to bind 
   2. Presenter as controller and model. 
   3. We do have Base Presenter (abstract with few generic implementations)
   4. We are having many such screens with all screen will have textbox in it and all screen presenter will extends Base Presenter.

-- My requirement is to fire and catch generic event when user changes any textbox in any screen.
-- I dont want to define event for each and every textboxes available in each screen.
-- I want to register all textbox on value change (ValueChangeHandler) event in generic.

Is there anyway we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to add a value change handler to each and every textbox that appear in a set of screens without adding to each individual text box.

You can extend the textbox and add value change handler in the constructor and provide a hook to do any manipuation.

```
public class MyTextBox extends TextBox
{
     public MyTextBox()
     {
           super();
           addValueChangeHandler( new ValueChangeHandler<String>()
           {

                @Override
                public void onValueChange( ValueChangeEvent<String> event )
               {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              }
           } );
      }
}
```